# How can you execute and array of Observables API calls where each API calls waits for the previous?

Tags: rxjs, observable

What I have been playing with is to use combineLatest with concatAll() but they are still being called simultaneously. I could just loop and call each but I am always wondering if there is a better way within the RXJS workflow.

```
combineLatest(arrayOfApiObservables).pipe(concatAll()).subscribe();
```

Comment: According to the documentation, the `concatAll()` executes each Observable one at a time: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/concatAll. But it's the `combineLatest` here that is already subscribing to each of the Observables.

Comment: I think you're looking for `concat(...arrayOfApiObservables)`

Comment: Yes, I tried the `concat` approach mentioned above and it seemed to provide the functionality you described.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you use the `combineLatest` operator, which will emit value only after all observables had emitted (e.g. it is calling everything simultaneously).

After that the `concatAll` can't affect the `arrayOfApiObservables` because they have alredy been called.

The right aproach is to create a higher-order observable (observable that emits observables), which can be achived with the help of the operator `from` and after that you can `concatAll` them to achive the desired result.

`concatAll` definition as seen in the docs:  `Converts a higher-order Observable into a first-order Observable by concatenating the inner Observables in order.`.

```js
let {
  interval,
  from
} = rxjs
let {
  take,
  concatAll,
  mapTo
} = rxjs.operators

let ref = document.querySelector('#container')

const obs1$ = interval(1000).pipe(take(1), mapTo('obs1'));
const obs2$ = interval(500).pipe(take(1), mapTo('obs2'));
const obs3$ = interval(2000).pipe(take(1), mapTo('obs3'));

let allObservables$ = from([obs1$, obs2$, obs3$])

allObservables$.pipe(
  concatAll()

).subscribe((x) => {
      console.log(x)
      container.innerHTML += `<div>${x}</div>`
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to be executed in a sequential manner, you could use concatMap() inside pipe().
Something like this:
of(1)
.pipe(
concatMap(result => {
console.log(result);
return of(2);
}),
concatMap(result => {
console.log(result);
return of(3);
}),
concatMap(result => {
console.log(result);
return of(4);
}),
concatMap(result => {
console.log(result);
return of(5);
}),
concatMap(result => {
console.log(result);
return of(6);
})
)
.subscribe(res => {
console.log("finish");
});

But, if you want to execute them all at once and then await for them until they are all completed, then just use forkJoin().